Raspberry Pi-Based Alternative to Fire TV Stick with HDMI CEC for Plex, PS Remote Play and Steam Link
I'm looking to replace my aging Fire TV Sticks with a Raspberry Pi-based alternative that meets the following requirements:

Plex: For media streaming (Kodi seems like a viable option here).
PS Remote Play: To stream games from my PlayStation.
Steam Link: To stream PC games from my desktop.
HDMI CEC: I want to control the setup using my TV remote via HDMI CEC, avoiding the need for an additional keyboard or mouse.

While Kodi appears to handle Plex quite well, I haven't found a way to use it to launch or integrate PS Remote Play or Steam Link.
I'm seeking recommendations for:

The best Raspberry Pi model and hardware configuration for this purpose.
Software or operating systems that allow seamless integration of these three functionalities.
Any workarounds or solutions to enable PS Remote Play and Steam Link alongside Kodi with HDMI CEC support. If you've successfully built a similar system or have insights into achieving this, I'd greatly appreciate your advice or resources.

Thank you in advance!
I installed Kodi with LibreELEC/Raspi OS and tried to write a Python Script that quits Kodi and launches PS Remote Play (didnt work/didnt work as expected) and also tried Android TV but that seems to have Problems with Hardware decoding and is quite laggy.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?
